# Setup CGI exe in IIS 7 - Will Always Download as .exe file instead of executing

Tags: iis-7, cgi

Trying to install a legacy `CGI.exe` file on a new Windows 2008 R2 server.

I added the `exe` path to the CGI and ISAPI restriction list (it is set to allowed).

The handler mapping for the `.exe` in the virtual directory is setup with execute permission also.

Every time I try and bring up the script in the browser, it will download the `.exe` as a file instead of running it on the server.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you added it under the "ISAPI and CGI Restrictions"?

Comment: Yes, see the second sentence of the description.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  Had to remove the MIME type for .exe, which translates to the below in web.config.

```
<staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".exe" />
</staticContent>
```

Legacy CGI application is displaying at 502 gateway error now but that is a different issue altogether :(